# Alternatives to Figma for Collaborative Online UI/UX Design?

Tags: collaboration

I'm currently exploring UI/UX design tools that enable effective online collaboration with my team. We've been using Figma, which has been quite beneficial, but I'm interested in discovering other platforms offering different features or workflows.

Could you recommend any platforms similar to Figma that are well-suited for UI/UX design, particularly those that facilitate seamless collaboration with coworkers in an online environment? I'm especially interested in tools that offer real-time collaboration, user-friendly interfaces, and robust design functionalities.